# Can't import packages using Swift 4 Package Manager

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, package-managers, swift4

Trying to test Swift 4 using Xcode-beta (v9) on my machine and having issues with importing packages into a test project:

- Initiated project using `swift package init --type executable`
- Changed `Package.swift` and added 2 projects to try out:

**Package.swift**

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "sampleproject",
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura.git", from: "1.7.6"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git", from: "4.5.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "sampleproject",
            dependencies: []),
    ]
)
```

- Run `swift build && swift package generate-xcodeproj`
- When I open project in Xcode-beta(v9) and try to import Kitura or Alamofire, I'm getting `No such module Kitura/Alamofire` error message
- Running `swift build` in terminal produces the following error:

> Compile Swift Module 'investprosto' (1 sources)
>   /Users/username/Projects/sampleproject/Sources/sampleproject/main.swift:1:8:
>   error: no such module 'Kitura' import Kitura
>          ^ error: terminated(1): /Applications/Xcode- beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-
>   build-tool -f /Users/username/Projects/sampleproject/.build/debug.yaml

**Dependencies** virtual folder contains the directories with the same package names, but they are empty. However, `.build\checkouts` and `.build\repositories` contain packages folders and corresponding files.

Is there something I'm missing in my system's configuration?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Turns out I had to also include the dependencies into the `.target` of the Package.swift:

```
.target(named: "sampleproject", dependencies: ["Kitura", "Alamofire"])
```

and build the project again.

Comment: Wow. That's not obvious from the docs https://swift.org/blog/swift-package-manager-manifest-api-redesign/. Then it seems one has to go to the URL for the git repo of the specific package to map it to the missing module. Because the import name isn't necessarily the same as the package name.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you need to add the `target` into the `Package.swift` sometimes it's not enough. I have fixed the issue by deleting the `.build` dir and the file `Package.resolved`, then running `swift build` or build from **Xcode**. Build command was not fetching packages as it was already in `resolved` file but if you delete the `.build` dir it becomes meaningless. You can verify it by checking the `Dependencies` dir from **Xcode** it will be empty if there is error like `No such package/module`